# clang ASTContext.getParents always returns an empty list

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing a tool for clang 4.0 using LibTooling based on the example [Clang ASTFrontendActions sample](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html). Given a current statement stmt, I want to get the immediate parent of it in the AST. So I try the below code to dump all parents of stmt (for testing purpose) :

```
bool VisitStmt(Stmt *s) {
    cout <<"Trying to get parents \n";
    const Stmt  currentStmt = *s;
    const auto& parents  = Context->getParents(currentStmt);
    auto it = Context->getParents(currentStmt).begin();
    if(it == Context->getParents(currentStmt).end())
        cout<< "parents not found\n";
    cout<<"parents size "<< parents.size() <<": \n";
    if (!parents.empty()){
        for (int i = 0; i< parents.size(); i++ ){
            cout<<"parent at "<< i <<": \n";
            const Stmt* parentStmt =  parents[i].get<Stmt>();
            parentStmt->dump();
        }

    }
}
```

`Context` is `ASTContext` and worked fine when I use other functions of it such as : `Context->getSourceManager()`
For all the statements visited, the result is always (regardless what I put in the input):

```
Trying to get parents 
parents not found
parents size 0:
```

Do I miss anything (initialization, setup) to use getParents?

Comment: I'm puzzled by `const Stmt  currentStmt = *s;`. I think you meant `const Stmt& currentStmt = *s;` I'm not sure if that's the cause of your issue, but that could very well fool clang into thinking it's an similar, but different, statement, which has no parent.

Comment: I have never worked with clang, but have worked with several other parsing/AST libraries. It is very common for some information to be unavailable at some (in general early) stages of the processing, even though the nodes' API still remains the same (basically because it would be way too much costly to recreate new nodes objects at each processing stages). Are you sure that the API doesn't specify such restriction on the getParents() function?

Comment: @Frank `const Stmt& currentStmt = *s;` did the trick, thanks. If you have good explanation, please answer below so I can mark your answer as the correct  ans

Comment: @jwatkins: I checked the document, seems like there's no such restriction.

Comment: you can use parentStmt->dumpPretty(*astContext); if the result of dump() confuses you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the following line:

```
const Stmt  currentStmt = *s;
```

What this does is make a copy of the statement. `Context->getParents()` works by looking for nodes that have the passed argument as a child. But since `currentStmt` only lives on your stack, and not within the context, it fails to find any such node.

By making `currentStmt` a reference to the node pointed by s:

```
const Stmt& currentStmt = *s;
```

Then you would be passing to the context the actual node instance that it has within itself, and clang will manage to find the parents successfully.